# How to add a line in the side column?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I would like to add a line between the single post titles, the single categories and the months in the right side column. (Here is the link, to show what I mean: www.veda-vit.de) 
Is there anybody who knows how I can do that? 
Thank you very much.
Greetings,
pradhana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;` to `.widget-title` if you want a line between the title and contents like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/50b6f862ied5hv6/Screenshot%202016-11-12%2007.24.05.jpg?dl=0 or if you'd like lines between each item like the screenshot below you would add the border CSS to `.widget-container ul li` https://www.dropbox.com/s/kn8pu2r4g7y6njt/Screenshot%202016-11-12%2007.23.48.jpg?dl=0

***Updated CSS***:

```
#secondary .widget-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: ...but two more questions: How do I increase the distance between the title and the line? And: How do I exclude the widget-titles in the footer? (Means I don't want to have the lines in the footer.)

Comment: So to exclude the footer you would just target widget titles in the sidebar, like so (also included the code to increase the spacing)–I'll update my answer with the code you need.